# Writing a string in console through VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am using the following code snippet

```
  Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec(".\lib\example.bat")
```

During this an empty console is getting opened till example.bat is completing it's process, is it possible to display some text  in that console??

I have tried echo in example.bat file but no use.

please help me with it

Comment: The output of the batch file is redirected to the StdOut property of your objExecObject allowing your vbscript to read it. So, no output to the screen will be seen. If you need to show content in the opened console, but not need to read batch output, use Run method instead of Exec.

Comment: @MCND I need to read batch output tatsy came for Exec method, is it possible to hide console window while using Exec method??

Comment: No, not possible with `Exec`.

Comment: If the script that is calling Exec is hidden, the spawned process window is also hidden.

Comment: @MCND Can you please explain it with my code snippet above

Answer (score 0):

Though displaying text in the console is not possible using exec, its possible to hide the console window using cscript and it worked.

Comment: That's not hiding the console window. It's just running in the console window you already have.